# Request.Form и конфликт преобразования типов

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, request, фильтрация

Доброго времени суток!

Передо мною стоит задача отфильтровать пользователю данные, доступные с бд. Изначальная мысль - записать значения юзера, введенные в формы в отдельные переменные, которые будут сравниваться со значениями в бд и отображаться( процесс фильтрации). Но через Request.Form работает будто исключительно для sting значений и вылазит ошибка:

```
 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "string" в "System.DateTime".
```

Модель:

```
 public class Apartment
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ApartmentId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Classes Class { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }


}

public enum Classes
{
    Econom,
    Standart,
    Luxury
}
```

Контроллер:

```
   public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
    {
        UserBook u = new UserBook();
        u.DateTimeStart = Request.Form["startdate"];
        return View(db.GetUserList());
    }
```

Вью:

```
  <div id="forms" class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Добро пожаловать, @User.Identity.GetUserName()</h2>
    <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
        <p>
            Введите количество людей:
            <input id="quan" type="number" name="quantity" method="post">

        <p>
            Выберете класс ваших аппартаментов:
            @Html.DropDownList("Class",
                            new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Classes))),
                            "Выберете класс",
                            new { @class = "form-control" })
        <p>
            Дату приезда:
            <input id="startdate" type="date" name="startdate" method="post">

        <p>
            Дату отъезда:
            <input id="enddate" type="date" name="enddate" method="post">

        <p>
            Find by name: <input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["currentFilter"]" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            <a asp-action="Index">Back to Full List</a>
        </p>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: не ясно, почему вы считаете, что вот это `u.DateTimeStart = Request.Form["startdate"];` будет работать?

Comment: @tym32167 есть какой-то правильный и рабочий аналог?

Comment: вы же вот эти параметры `string sortOrder, string searchString` как то принимаете, почему бы остальные параметры не сделать по аналогии?

Comment: @tym32167 эти параметры - никак не юзаются в коде, это просто были попытки сделать как указано в документации, которую вы мне кидали под другим вопросом

Comment: ну значит уберите их и укажите те параметры, что вам нужны